# Create instance from attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, mef

I'm using **MVVM viewmodel-first** pattern in a **WPF** application and I have some definitions like these:

```
public interface IMyView { }

[Export(typeof(IMyView))]
public class MyView : UserControl, IMyView { }

[ViewTypeAttribute(typeof(IMyView))]
public interface IMyViewModel { }

[Export(typeof(IMyViewModel))]
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase, IMyViewModel { }
```

That the `ViewTypeAttribute` is a custom attribute to retrive which `View` should be used as `DataTemplate` for the given `ViewModel`. Really here I have a `Type`! But I don't know how to create an instance from that `Type` via `MEF`? can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
var container = new CompositionContainer(/* your container .ctor here */);
var type = typeof (IYourType); // read the type from attribute
var export = container.GetExports(type, null, null).FirstOrDefault();
var obj = export.Value as YourCostingHere;
```

Answer (score 0):

why you dont use the built in wpf stuff to get the right view for your viewmodel? if you simply create a datatemmplate for your viewmodel and set the right view/usercontrol. then all its done.

```
<DataTemplate DataType={vm:IMyViewModel}>
  <local:MyIViewUserControl />
</DataTemplate>
```

any where in your app where you bind your viewmodel to a contentcontrol its rendered as the MyIViewUserControl.

EDIT: maybe i'm wrong, but i thought you use your ViewTypeAttribute (MEF Export Attribute) to get the linkin between view and viewmodel. And then you wanna create a datatemplate with this information?

so why not export the DataTemplate directly and add it to the app.resources?

Comment: Because of my design requirements!!! Your `A` is not the answer for my question! please read it again